# appear button behind a div from right - CSS

Tags: html, css

i write this code to make appear a button behind a div from right but its not working when i hover button itself(#appear)

```css
#main{
  height:20px;
  width:200px;
  background-color:#c1c1c1;
  position:relative;
}
#appear{
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  background-color:red;
  z-index:-100;
}
#main:hover #appear,#appear:hover{
  right:-20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="appear">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `hover` use javascript events, like `onmouseenter`.  Hover take the effect when you only place your mouse pointer on the element. Visit this link for more info:
[JSEvents](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseenter.asp)

Comment: I use js but i still have that problem. becuase the child tag is not located inside the parent and when leave the parent the child style will be in active as well.

Comment: @SoroushBk check your code, I think your child tag (`<div id="appear"></div>`) is located inside the parent `(<div id="main"></div>)`. Use other JS Events rather if it wont work.

Comment: @SoroushBk you can also put two JS events like `onmouseleave`, Check out this link: [clickMe](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onmouseenter)